# Can anyone suggest books for SharePoint project development and administration in SP2010 and SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, office-365-developer, architecture, books

I am looking for resources to know about implementation of concepts in SharePoint in real world project right from architecture design.

Free/purchased books to learn architecture design, development and administration of SharePoint 2010/2013/Office 365.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real world implementation details for SharePoint are available from the below resources

[Amazon - Real World SharePoint 2010: Indispensable Experiences from 22 MVPs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470597135)

[Amazon - Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Designing and Architecting Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735671680)

[Free Resource TechNet - Solutions for the real world in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872147.aspx)